# face properties of decomposable cones

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-cone

I have a convex cone $H$ that is the convex hull of two other convex cones $F$ and $G$. Furthermore, for all $f\in \mathsf{faces}(F)$, $g\in \mathsf{faces}(G)$ we have that $\mathsf{conv}(f,g)\in \mathsf{faces}(H)$ (e.g. the convex hull of any face of $F$ with any face of $G$ is also a face). Does this imply that $H$ is decomposable into $H=F\oplus G$ (e.g. $G$ and $F$ have disjoint spans)?

It seems that it should imply this by some simple dimensional argument..

Comment: 1) Is a cone for you a symmetrical volume wrt to its vertex, or only a half of it ? 2) The convex hull of two cones is not a cone in general :for example the convex hull of cone $z^2=x^2+y^2 (z>0)$ and $z^2=(x-1)^2+y^2$ contains in its boundary the line segment from (0,0,0) to (1,0,0).

Comment: @JeanMarie: The latter is not a cone, zero must be in the closure of a cone.